# when I update data,how to get data from db with CJuiDatePicker?

Tags: database, yii

when I use CJuiDatePicker in yii,I want to get data when I in the opdate page.but the CJuiDatePicker can't get data from the database.The follow is the code,

```
    <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'name'=>'B2bTicket[examdate]',
            'attribute' => 'B2bTicket[examdate]',
            // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
            'options'=>array(
                'altField' => 'examdate',
                'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                'showAnim'=>'slide',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                'autocomplete' => 'true' 
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'height:20px;background-color:white;color:#000;',
            ),
        ));
    ?>
```

can anyone help me solve the problem?
my question is that I can't get data  from db automatic when I in the update page.

Answer (score 1):

Add value option.

```
<?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
            'name'=>'B2bTicket[examdate]',
            'attribute' => 'B2bTicket[examdate]',
            'value' => $model->isNewRecord?date("Y-m-d"):$model->examdate,//here is the line!           
            // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
            'options'=>array(
                'altField' => 'examdate',
                'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
                     'showAnim'=>'slide',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                'autocomplete' => 'true' 
            ),
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                'style'=>'height:20px;background-color:white;color:#000;',
            ),
        ));
    ?>
```

This will show current date on create page and attribute value date on update.

Comment: there are another question,I also want to type the datetime directly,not only through the calendar.How can I make it?

Comment: Just type in input in dateFormat. It works for me, idk were is your problem.